# Redirecting to another page, using variables from the first one

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have created the following scenario.

1. I have the index.php file which shows the mainpage. On this there are two fields - User Id and password enclosed in a form tag. The submit button calls the login.php file.
2. Login.php validates the user id, password etc
3. Once validation is successful, I want the login.php page to take me to MyDashboard.php page (passing the User Id and Password along).

   I tried Header in PHP but does not work. I also tried to do a Javascript window.location.href and tried to call it on $(document).ready but nothing happens.

   Please help.

--- Edit ----
here is the code after modification

```
   <?php
      include_once('./library/Common.php');
      $_EmailId = trim($_POST['validemailid']);
      $_Password = trim($_POST['password1']);
      $_Rememberme = trim($_POST['rememberme']);

      // Get the username from the Email Id by searching for @

      $_UName= substr($_EmailId, 0, strpos($_EmailId, '@'));

      $_Password = md5($_Password);

      session_start();

      $_SESSION['username'] = $_UName;



      $query = "select username, firstname, password_hash,userstatus from users where username = ? and emailid = ?";


      $dbconn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','myDB');

      if($dbconn->connect_errno)
      {
        print getHTML('ERROR', "Error in connecting to mysql".$dbconn->connect_error);
      }

      if(!($stmt=$dbconn->prepare($query)))
      {
        print getHTML('ERROR',"error in preparing sql statement".$dbconn->error);
      }

      if(!($stmt->bind_param('ss',$_UName,$_EmailId)))
      {
        print getHTML('ERROR',"error in binding params in sql statement".$stmt->error);
      }

      if(!$stmt->execute())
      {
        print getHTML('ERROR',"Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error);
      }

      $result=$stmt->get_result();
      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

      $_dbpwd = $row['password_hash'];
      $_userstatus = $row['userstatus'];

      $errstatus = false;


      if ($row['username'] != $_UName)
      {
        print getHTML('ERROR',"User does not exist with the given email id: ".$_EmailId);

        $errstatus = true;
      }   

      if(($row['password_hash'] != $_Password) && !$errstatus)
      {
        print getHTML('ERROR',"Password does not match");
        $errstatus = true;          
      }

      if(($row['userstatus'] != 'ACTIVE') && !$errstatus)
      {
        print getHTML('ERROR',"User is inactive. Please check your email for activation");
        $errstatus = true;
      }

      if(!$errstatus)
      {
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
        $chksession = "SELECT sessionid FROM USERSESSIONS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND ENDDATE IS NULL";

        if(!($sessionstmt=$dbconn->prepare($chksession)))
        {
            print "error in preparing sql statement".$dbconn->error;
            exit();
        }


        $sessionstmt->bind_param('s',$_UName);

        $sessionstmt->execute();


        $sessionresult=$sessionstmt->get_result();

        $sessionrow= $sessionresult->fetch_assoc();

        $currdate = date('y-m-d H:i:s');




        if($sessionrow['sessionid'] == 0)
        {
            $insertstmt = $dbconn->query("INSERT INTO USERSESSIONS(USERNAME,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) VALUES ('".$_UName."','".$currdate."',null)");

            $insertstmt->close();
        } 
      }

      $sessionstmt->close();
      $stmt->close();
      $dbconn->close();

      header("Location :MyDashboard.php");
      exit;

          ?>
      --- End of Edit -----
```

Amit

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried?

Comment: the code is like this <?php does some validation chech ?> $(document).ready(function(){ window.location.href("MyDashboard.php?username="+<?php echo $_Uname ;?>);});

Comment: The magic word is "Session".

Comment: Can you please explain...I am new to PHP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transfer variables between PHP pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240470/transfer-variables-between-php-pages)

Comment: I checked the page mentioned and it is not a duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

You should use session variables to store variables within a login session. Passing a password along to other pages is not recommended, nor necessary. Read up on [Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), and take a look at already existing login scripts. Below is a *very simple* example, redirecting to the next page using the [`header()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

```
<?php

// Validate user credentials and save to session
session_start();
$_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;

// Redirect to next page
header("Location: dashboard.php");

// Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect
exit;

?>
```

Comment: better use session and header() without params yes.

Answer (score 2):

If user authenticated,
In PHP:

```
header('Location:MyDashboard.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [include()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

This function allows you to include code from other php scripts.

Comment: No...I want to open a freshpage...MyDashboard.php

Answer (score 0):

The header function is the correct way. As long as you don't have any output before calling the header function, it should work.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Post your code, and let's see what it is that isn't working!

Comment: Posted my code...can you advise what I am doing that is causing this issue... I even tried with javascript... <script> window.location.href("MyDashboard.php") </script>

Answer (score 0):

Header should work in your condition.

Tou can use following code:

```
header("Location:filename");
exit();
```