# how to send php variable to another php page?

Tags: php

First, I send the id to rec_update.php file like this:

```
location.href="http://localhost/pk/rec_update.php?id="+id;
```

On rec_update.php file, I access that value like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Now, I want to send this $id to rec_update1.php file. which can be called by clicking a button. On button I have applied a javascript function from where page will directs to rec_update1.php
How do I get this value on another php file.

Comment: It depends your code. If you use objects, it is very simple to put it as a parameter of your call....

Comment: I mean, you could just pass the GET variable to the next page again? Or even use sessions/cookies.

Comment: Try session variable

Comment: Why you don't use $_SESSION[] ?

Comment: It depends on your code. You also able to use ajax for passing data to another page.

Comment: what do you mean by directing by js?

Comment: When you use javascript for redirecting you can put $id to your url in javascript to pass it through using + var_name + do not forget to add $id to a javascript var

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer variables between PHP pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240470/transfer-variables-between-php-pages)

Answer (score 1):

> HTML / HTTP is stateless, in other words, what you did / saw on the
>   previous page, is completely disconnected with the current page.
>   Except if you use something like sessions, cookies or GET / POST
>   variables. Sessions and cookies are quite easy to use, with session
>   being by far more secure than cookies. More secure, but not completely
>   secure

.

**Session:**

```
<?php
//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
?>
```

> Remember to run the session_start() statement on both these pages
>   before you try to access the $_SESSION array, and also before any
>   output is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

> In rec_update.php

```
<script>
    location.href="http://localhost/pk/rec_update1.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>";
</script>
```

> And in rec_update1.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```