# How to automatically check a radio button based on another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two (2) forms(div : wizard form):

- The first form(div) asks the user to check a radio button
- The second form (div) is for verification if the user want to change something

The problem is in the second form:

How I can automatically check the same radio button in the second form that the user checked in the first form?

I have a radio button the choose between `YES` and `NO`.

So, If the user selects the `YES` button, I need the `YES` button checked automatically in the second form(div).

The code:

```js
yes_no = $('input[name="test"]:checked').val();

alert(yes_no);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step1">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Test </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-xs" id="label_mobile_yes">
      
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="yes" value="yes">YES</label>
      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="no" value="test2">NO</label>
      
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="step2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Test </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-xs" id="label_mobile_yes">
      
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="yes_yes" value="yes">YES</label>
      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="no_no" value="test2">NO</label>
      
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665915/how-to-check-a-radio-button-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Hi Alexis, you would need to persist your data between pages, you should try using Session. See the following article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240470/transfer-variables-between-php-pages

Comment: @CraigMayers I need javascript not PHP the two form is in the same page ( wizard form )

Comment: Can you show the second form also, that way we can offer specific help; this *should* be simple enough to implement, but it's better for you - and future visitors - if we can show a specific example of the implementation.

Comment: @DavidThomas I add all code

Comment: You have two elements with an `id` of `yes`, and two elements with an `id` of `no`; this is invalid HTML; an `id` must be unique within the document.

Comment: if you use name="test" for all radio button  its look  bad

Comment: @DavidThomas I change it without result and I use this function `$("#yes").prop("checked", true);`

Comment: try my updated answer @saadsaad

Comment: @saadsaad i have implemented the similar functionality in the fiddler check once https://jsfiddle.net/t651ujm0/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#step1 input').on('change', function() {
   alert($('input[name=test]:checked', '#step1').val()); 
   
   if($('input[name=test]:checked', '#step1').val()=='yes')
 {
   
     $('#yes1').prop("checked", true);
   }
   else
 {
  $('#no1').prop("checked", true);
   
   }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step1">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Test </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-xs" id="label_mobile_yes">
      
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="yes" value="yes">YES</label>
      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="no" value="test2">NO</label>
      
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="step2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Test </label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-xs" id="label_mobile_yes">
      
    <input type="radio" name="test1" class="test" id="yes1" value="yes">YES</label>
      
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
    <input type="radio" name="test1" class="test" id="no1" value="test2">NO</label>
      
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding I have created a fiddler for the same and coding standard(HTML naming) is bad.

https://jsfiddle.net/t651ujm0/5/

```
$("input[name='test']").click(function(){
      $("input[name='test1'][value='"+$(this).val()+"']").attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do any of this...

> $("#radio_1").prop("checked", true)
>
> For versions of jQuery prior to 1.6, use:
>
> $("#radio_1").attr('checked', 'checked');

Comment: I try but without any result

Comment: can you please show code for both form and when you want to pass value actually to second form?

Comment: please check my answer below...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#form1 input').on('change', function() {
   alert($('input[name=test]:checked', '#form1').val()); 
   
   if($('input[name=test]:checked', '#form1').val()=='yes')
     {
       
         $('.'+$('input[name=test]:checked', '#form1').val(),'#form1').prop("checked", true);
       }
   else
     {
      $('.'+$('input[name=test]:checked', '#form1').val(),'#form1').prop("checked", true);
       
       }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form1" id="form1" >
 
  
<div class="div1">
<input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="yes" value="yes">YES
  
<label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
<input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="no" value="no">NO</label>
</div>
  
  
<div class="div2">
<input type="radio" name="test1" class="yes"  value="yes">YES
  
<label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
<input type="radio" name="test1" class="no" value="no">NO</label>
</div >
 </form>
```

Comment: It I wizard form ( multiphase ) so, I use 1 form but I use 2 div ( I make 2 form in the title to explain more )

Answer (score 0):

Details are commented in Snippet

#### SNIPPET

```js
// When DOM content is ready
$(function() {

  var no = $('input[name="test"][value="no"]');
  var yes = $('input[name="test"][value="yes"]');
  var neg = $('input[name="result"][value="neg"]');
  var pos = $('input[name="result"][value="pos"]');

  // Delegate the click event on [no] only
  no.on('click', function(e) {
    neg.prop('checked', true);
  });

  // Delegate the click event on [yes] only
  yes.on('click', function(e) {
    pos.prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='f1' name='f1'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Test</label>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-xs" id="label_mobile_yes">

          <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="yes" value="yes">YES</label>

        <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
          <input type="radio" name="test" class="test" id="no" value="no">NO</label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form id='f2' name='f2'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 2</legend>

    <label>
      <input type='radio' name='result' value='neg'>Neg</label>
    <label>
      <input type='radio' name='result' value='pos'>Pos</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something similar to the following approach, in which the elements are selected using a common custom, `data-*`, attribute which allows for simple selection and, having cached the collection, allows for easy filtering of that collection to target the appropriate elements to change.

Also, I've changed the `name` attributes a little into 'groups,' otherwise only one radio `<input>` from any number of elements sharing the same `name` property could be `checked`.

```js
// caching the relevant elements, here we select <input> elements,
// of 'type=radio' which have a custom data-choice attribute:
var choices = $('input[type=radio][data-choice]');

// use the on() method to bind the anonymous function of the
// method as the event-handler for the 'change' event on
// those elements:
choices.on('change', function() {

  // retrieving the value of the data-choice attribute
  // dataset property of the changed element:
  var choice = this.dataset.choice;

  // filtering the cached collection of elements to those
  // which have the 'data-choice' attribute which is equal
  // to the value of the changed <input> element:
  choices.filter('[data-choice=' + choice + ']')

  // setting the 'checked' property of that element to the
  // same state as the changed element:
  .prop('checked', this.checked)

  // this is just to visibly demonstrate the effectiveness
  // and can be discarded in your use-case, however here
  // we move to the parent elements of the retained
  // <input> elements:
  .parent()

  // and add the 'checked' class to those parents:
  .addClass('checked')

  // selecting the sibling elements of those parents:
  .siblings()

  // and removing the 'checked' class:
  .removeClass('checked');
});
```

```css
label.checked {
  color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Test</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-xs" id="label_mobile_yes">

          <!-- note that I've removed the id attribute from the
               radio <input> elements, since you can use alternative
               custom attributes to select, and group, them; here
               we use the 'data-choice' custom attribute, with the
               (obvious) values of 'yes' and 'no' to reflect the
               user-choice: -->
          <input type="radio" name="testGroup1" class="test" data-choice="yes" value="yes">YES</label>

        <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
          <input type="radio" name="testGroup1" class="test" data-choice="no" value="test2">NO</label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div id="step2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Test</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-default btn-on btn-xs" id="label_mobile_yes">

          <input type="radio" name="testGroup2" class="test" data-choice="yes" value="yes">YES</label>

        <label class="btn btn-default btn-off btn-xs" id="label_mobile_no">
          <input type="radio" name="testGroup2" class="test" data-choice="no" value="test2">NO</label>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).